# Why does VBScript sometimes block in WshShell.Exec?

Tags: vbscript, wmi, hta, wmic

I've got an html application (HTA) that uses WshShell.Exec to get the version of Windows.  I'm using `wmic os get Caption` to get the specific version, which works fine on the command line and in a batch script.  I've also tested the way I'm calling `WshShell.Exec` and it works fine with other commands (i.e. `echo Windows 2008`).  The problem occurs when I try to combine these things the Exec seems to just freeze.  Can you recommend a way around this?  Here's my code:

```
Function GetWinVersion
    'Returns 2008, XP, or 7
    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    set oExec = WshShell.Exec("wmic os get Caption")
    do while oExec.Status = 0
        'I added this very busy wait, though it doesn't seem to help
        'Would sleep if it was available in an hta
    loop
    While oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream <> True
        thisLine = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
        'MsgBox "Found line: " & thisLine
        if InStr(thisLine, "2008") > 0 then
            GetWinVersion=2008
            Exit Function
        elseif InStr(thisLine, "XP") > 0 then
            GetWinVersion=XP
            Exit Function
        elseif InStr(thisLine, "Windows 7") > 0 then
            GetWinVersion=7
            Exit Function
        end if
    Wend
    MsgBox "Error parsing output of wmic os get Caption"
    self.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMIC is a wrapper for WMI, which you can use directly in VBS;

```
function GetWinVersion
    dim WMI: set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    dim colResults: set colResults = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
    dim item
    for each item in colResults
        GetWinVersion = item.caption
    next
end function
```

Comment: +1 That gets my code working.  Thanks.  Any idea as to why Exec was blocking?  I've heard of this causing problems elsewhere also and want to know why so I don't get caught again.

Comment: No, I got the same results, try examining the output of StdErr?